# Problem with overlay of 2 elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="height:500px">
<ul style="height: 1000px">
....
</ul>
</div>
```

I am using the UL as Jquery carousel.
My problem is that the div won't act as a 500px window above that UL carousel,
and it seems like its streching the DIV so it will also fit the 1000px.

How can this be solved?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to tell whats happening aside those two code lines but you would also need to set in the css that the div should have overflow hidden so that no content will flow over the height

Answer (score 3):

try `<div style="height:500px; overflow: hidden">`